# Webdriver selenium on click function and switch to a different tab in azure to fetch employee data using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to fetch employee data into an excel from Azure portal using Python code. The landing page shows the list of employees, click each employee name, switch to properties tab, then fetch details displayed such as First name, Country, Job title. This should be done iteratively.

Adding the image to make it clear. Here, URL takes me to the landing page. It has several employee names and they are links. Once clicked, it takes to the page2 which has 2 tabs - Overview and Properties. Once clicked onto Properties tab, it displays the data that we need to fetch. This has to be done recursively for each employee.
[image]

What the code does now - Connects to the Azure portal successfuly and lands on the page that has the employee list. The click() function is not working and it does not switch to properties tab. Can anyone please suggest what can be modified for the code to work?

The error I get now is -> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='ms-Pivot-text text-135'][normalize-space()='Properties']"}

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import openpyxl

# Create a new Excel workbook and select the active worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet.append(["Name", "Country", "Job Title"])

# Set up Chrome WebDriver (make sure to download the chromedriver executable)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the target URL
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
names=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='abcgridcol6']//div[@class='azc-grid-headerlabel'][normalize-space()='Name']")
# Iterate through each name, click on it, and extract necessary information
for name in names:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    name.click()  # Click on the name to view its properties
properties_tab = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ms-Pivot-text text-135'][normalize-space()='Properties']")
    properties_tab.click()

    # Extract first name, country, and job title
    first_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@for='PropertyItem71']").text
    country = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Country')]/following-sibling::div").text
    job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Job Title')]/following-sibling::div").text
    sheet.append([first_name, country, job_title])
    
    # Go back to the previous page to continue looping
    driver.back()

# Save the Excel workbook
workbook.save("employee_data.xlsx")

# Close the WebDriver session
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

i can help with this!

if you are able to share the URl you are using it would be easier. However i would suggest using the class or tag to find the element. example

```
#this will return all the buttons on the page
buttons = driver.find_element(By.TAGNAME, 'button') 

for button in buttons:
    if button.Text == 'Properties'
        properties_Button = button
        properties_Button.click
```

this should click on the properties button for you if you need to click on multiple buttons then you should grab the </div/> class that holds the buttons and iterate through them again if we have the URL link then i could write a more detailed code for it. i Hope this helps happy coding! :)

Comment: I have added an image to clarify my requirement further. URL is internal, so I won't be able to share.

Comment: No worries are you able to share the code? so if you inspect the element you want to click it should look like this -----> <button type="submit" class="s-btn s-btn__filled">Add comment</button>

Or some version of this if you can supply that i could try and write a script close to it.

Comment: Given this is internal the information is confidential i could always offer a web call if that would be better as it would allow greater flexibility in solving the issue.  if not im more than happy to offer whatever guidance i can here to help :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I can't show the portal and data. I will try whatever you suggested and I could get the data from Azure using powershell scripts.

Comment: Hey Sorry i havent replied in a few days i was attending a  Python conference. so i have a plan to make this work if you can send me the Div that holds the Employee URLS just copy the inner HTML and post it in the code and i can modify my answer step by step.

Comment: <div data-bind="text: name" class="abc-headerlabel">Name</div> -> This is for the name element but the script has to go into this and then to Properties tab to fetch information. I am not sure whether there is a restriction on data extraction since we are unable to extract any data from that website. I would recommend not to spend time on this as an alternate solution has been found. Thanks!